# How I can save each image in different folder for each click in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

I am using **gallery_saver** package for saving image.

I want when I press the capture button Image will save different folder for each click. How I can archive it? Please help me.

**Save Image method here:**

```
CameraController? controller;
  void _takePhoto() async {
    try {
      if (controller != null) {
        if (controller!.value.isInitialized) {
          image = await controller!.takePicture();
        
          try{
            GallerySaver.saveImage(image!.path);
          } catch(e) {
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Image not saved" + e.toString());
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e); //show error
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy file data to another location
And give that file to gallery saver.

```dart
CameraController? controller;
    void _takePhoto() async {
      try {
        if (controller != null) {
          if (controller!.value.isInitialized) {
            XFile? image = await controller!.takePicture();
            
            // Read file and save it to new location
            final buffer = await image.readAsBytes();
            await new File(<newPath>).writeAsBytes(buffer);
            
            // Give that new path to Gallerysaver
            try{
              GallerySaver.saveImage(<newPath>);
            } catch(e) {
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Image not saved" + e.toString());
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e); //show error
      }
    }
```

Comment: newPath means ? Please clear this portion.

Comment: New path means different folder location..